# Upgrade FreeLander PD80 Vogue QuadCore 9.7 inch Android 4.0 tablet to Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm about to buy a FreeLander PD80 Vogue QuadCore 9.7 inch Android 4.0 tablet, but it has ICS. Can I safely upgrade to Jelly Bean? The website where I am buying from says that the warranty will be void if I upgrade to another Android OS.

I am a complete novice. So, I'd be grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is a common policy for resellers to cancel the warranty if the buyer upgrades the ROM. Several manufactures though allow upgrading for their official ROMs, but I am afraid this is not the case for Freelander, for which unfortunately I have not found any official ROM (at least not in Chinese). I am not sure what are the legal aspects of such policies. In any case there is a risk involved when upgrading a device that the device may be 'bricked', ie be rendered unusable if something goes wrong.

Now regarding the ROMs for the particular device, I believe I have found mainly two alternatives.

The first is to use a ROM from a similar Ainol device. The link for the ROM is http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=352175935&uk=420337580 (use Google translate to identify the download button which should be the second at the right hand side).

The update procedure along with some testimonials can be found on:
http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/82866-android-422-on-freelander-pd80-wise/

According to those testimonials, the only thing not working properly after the upgrade is the front camera.

The second alternative is to use one of the Cyanogenmod ROMs ([10.2](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/97866-custom-rom-cyanogenmod-11-442-for-allwinner-a31-by-christiantroy-update-2014-02-01/) or [11](http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/97866-custom-rom-cyanogenmod-11-442-for-allwinner-a31-by-christiantroy-update-2014-02-01/)) for Allwinner A31 device. In the above links you can find all relevant information, along with whatever may go wrong.

I have not yet evaluated any of these but I will eventually as I own such a device and the existing ROM is nonsense. Please provide any feedback when available.